# BIP44 with ed25519 curve signature

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, ed25519

I want to use `BIP44 HD` wallet with `Ed25519` curve. Does `BIP 44` support the `Ed25519` curve, Because I have read that `BIP32` does not compatible with  `Ed25519` based cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

[BIP-0044](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) depends on [BIP-0043](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0043.mediawiki), which depends on [BIP-0032](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki), which only supports secp256k cryptography in its original form. Since then [SLIP-0010](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md) defined a way to extend BIP32 with NIST-P256 and Ed25519 cryptography, so I suggest to delve yourself into SLIP-0010. Unfortunately Ed25519 does not support normal (public) derivation, only hardened derivation. So you cannot have read-only wallets or audited accounts for Ed25519-based crypto.